# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$page_title' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/pensemos/public_html/gestionelo/gestionelo/1_view/login.php on line 22

Tags: php

Me aparece este error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$page_title' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/pensemos/public_html/gestionelo/gestionelo/1_view/login.php on line 22

```
?php
if ( ! session_id() ) session_start();

$_SESSION['Email'] = "";
$_SESSION["IdUserNet"] = "";
$_SESSION["IdEmpresa"] = "";
$_SESSION["IdUsuario"] = "";
$_SESSION["Alias"] = "";
$_SESSION["NivelAdmin"] = "";
session_destroy();

 //initilize the page
 require_once 'init.php';


$page_title = "Login";
```

Comment: que hay en `init.php` ?

Comment: debes postear el init.php

Answer (score 0):

Este es init.php

```
//configure constants
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('EOL', PHP_EOL);
define('__DEV__', getenv('DEV') === 'on');

//configuration variables
$page_title = "";
 $page_css = array();
 $no_main_header = false; //set true for lock.php and login.php
 $page_body_prop = array(); //optional properties for <body>
 $page_html_prop = array(); //optional properties for <html>

 if (!isset($argv)) {
    $argv = array(isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ? $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] : 
      _FILE__);
$args_list = isset($_GET['argv']) && is_array($_GET['argv']) ? $_GET['argv'] : $_GET;

foreach ($args_list as $key => $value) {
    if ($value) $argv[] = $value;
}
```

}

```
   if (Common\Util::is_cli()) {
  $document_root = realpath(isset($argv[1]) && is_dir($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : 
 dirname(__DIR__));
$server_name = gethostname();
$request_uri = str_replace(DS, '/', substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 
strlen($document_root)));
} else {
$document_root = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$server_name = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  }

     $document_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on' ? 'https' : 
  'http').'://'.$server_name;

$app_path = $document_root;
$app_url = $document_url;

 if (strpos(__DIR__, $document_root) === 0) {
$app_uri = substr(__DIR__, strlen($document_root));
$app_path .= $app_uri;
$app_url .= str_replace(DS, '/', $app_uri);
} 

define('DOCUMENT_ROOT', $document_root);
define('SERVER_NAME', $server_name);
define('SERVER_URL', $document_url);
define('SERVER_REQUEST', $document_url.$request_
```